# Axios ReactJs Laravel: How to retrieve the multiple request Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I create new laravel project and I combine the React Javascript Framework. 
I watch youtube and read some website, how to use the Axios HTTP Requests API.
however they not discuss how to use the axios in retrieving the multiple request api.

**Question:**

How to retrieve multiple request api and also I want to display it to my render function

I create two public function (Mission,Store) in my **Home Controller**.

```
public function mission() {
    $content_mission = DB::table('content_structure')
    ->where('content_pages','=','Home')
    ->where('content_section','=','Mission-Vision')
    ->where('status','=','Active')
    ->orderBy('content_id','Desc')
    ->limit(1)
    ->get();

    return response()->json($content_mission);
}


public function store() {
    $content_store = DB::table('content_structure')
    ->leftJoin('content_upload_assets','content_structure.content_id','=','content_upload_assets.cid')
    ->where('content_pages','=','Home')
    ->where('content_section','=','Store')
    ->where('status','=','Active')
    ->orderBy('content_id','Desc')
    ->limit(1)
    ->get();

    return response()->json($content_store);
}
```

I also create Index.js to my component folder.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {

    }

  }

  componentWillMount() {

    this.setState({
      missionsApiRes: []
    });

    Promise.all([
      axios.get('/api/mission'),
      axios.get('/api/store')
    ]).then(response => {
      const [storesApiRes, missionsApiRes] = response;
      this.setState({storesApiRes,missionsApiRes}, () => {

      });
    })
  }



  renderMission() {
    return this.state.missionsApiRes.map(mission => 
      <div>{mission.content}</div>
    )
  }
```

**My Render Function :**

```
 <div className="container">
     {this.renderMission()}
 </div>
```

**Error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: this.state.missionsApiRes.map is not a function

Comment: Usually this happens when 'missionsApiRes' returns an Object. I think map function works with Array

Answer (score 1):

From quick glance I would say that your `this.state.missionsApiRes` is not defined at the time of calling render. Try to move it to the constructor:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    missionsApiRes: []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need custom resolve data of axios promise

```
Promise.all([
  axios.get('/api/mission'), => axios.get('/api/mission').then(data => data)
```